# Tempest Installation in Openstack

Tags: openstack

I am very new to openstack and using tempest for testing. Please let me know the clear steps to install the tempest and required python packages needs to be installed. I have installed tempest in Ubuntu from github. And got stucked please help me to run the sample tests for my openstack

Thanks,
KM

Answer (score 0):

try checking out run_tests.sh in the code base for each openstack project.

this shell script executes a full battery of tests on each component of openstack.

more information on openstack testing is available on their wiki:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Testing

Answer (score 0):

If devstack is used , tempest will be automatically configured in /opt/stack/tempest/. While setting up devstack user will be prompted for password for couple of questions and same will be configure in tempest.conf which is present in /opt/stack/tempest/etc/tempest.conf file.

However, if openstack multinode cluster is to be tested, then you have understand the configuration of tempest, yes there is lot to configure if the cluster has all openstack services running...

Openstack document is pretty neat, can be followed at http://docs.openstack.org/developer/tempest/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Tempest can be installed from source for the latest development version:

```
$ git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack/tempest
$ cd tempest
$ pip install .
```

or from pypi for a release version. For the latest release use:

```
$ pip install tempest
```

You may want to install Tempest in a virtual environment, however if you do so and if you have Tempest plugins installed, make sure that either the plugins are installed in the same virtual environment. If your plugins are installed in the system path, you can enable site-packages in the Tempest virtual environment to make them discoverable by Tempest.

If you use devstack for development, Tempest is installed and configured by default to match your development cloud configuration.

If you use another deployment mechanism, look for module to configure Tempest as it may already exists (e.g. [openstack-ansible-os_tempest](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-os_tempest) if you use openstack-ansible.

If no existing mechanism is available for your deployment methodology, you can still configure Tempest "by hand", even though I would recommend automating the process. In most cases you will only need to tweak a few configuration items, typically the access credentials for your cloud. 
Pick a folder you want to run Tempest from:

```
   $ cd [folder]
   $ # Create a vanilla configuration file
   $ tempest init
   $ # Customise the config file in [folder]/etc/tempest.conf
   $ # Run tempest
   $ tempest run
```

Have a look at the [configuration guide](https://docs.openstack.org/tempest/latest/configuration.html) for reference.